# Is there a simple way to run 5 different instances of the same code?

Tags: node.js

Hey im working on a node project that basically requires me to run 5 different accounts for one service. The code to start one is simple but I can't figure out how to linearly assign a name to it.

I've been trying to research how this works or if this is even possible but have had no luck finding what I'm looking for. I'm not sure if this is something that should be completely handled in a child process? I haven't had any luck getting one to work.

```
function startSession(client, credentials) {
    const aNameHere = bm.newInstance()
}
```

Credentials object example:

```
    "Account1": {
        "name": "user",
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
    }
```

I want the value of credentials.name to be where aNameHere is. but Im not rlly sure how to accomplish that. I was hoping there was a way I could essentials linearly create these so that I could end up having 5 instances all named user[1-5]

Comment: Edit: the person who commented suggesting pm2 removed their comment. I was originally thinking of using pm2 for this, However I want them to be accessible through other parts of my main application. And using pm2 would separate them from the main process

Comment: you could define the containing variable outside of the function and make it an array. Then you can just push the new instances into this array. Like
`const aNameHere = [];
function startSession(client, credentials){
    aNameHere.push(bm.newInstance());
}`
And then just call the instances like aNameHere[0-n].someProp

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Using_the_Map_object) data type.

Make sure that names is unique, or it will override the other.

```
   var myMap = new Map();

  function startSession(client, credentials) {
       myMap.set(credentials.name) = bm.newInstance();
  }

  myMap.get(credentials.name);
  myMap.get(user);
```

Comment: I tried your example. I am receiving the error `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` The error is coming from `client.accounts.set(credentials.username) = bm.newInstance();`

Comment: No, it's not the same i mentioned, you have to define new map first and add key and value inside map, just copy paste the code will work, and you can access the bm.instance from myMap by get function.